# Passing data from Activity to Fragment shows nothing

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an Activity that hosts a fragment. From that fragment I start another Activity (if certain button is pressed). This Activity is a Recycler View that chooses an image and I want to retrieve this image ID and pass it to my fragment (so it can display the correct image). I tried to do a test to pass data but it doesn't work.
ImageGallery.java <- Activity where the images are:

```
  @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_image_gallery);
        RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.imagegallery);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        images = new ArrayList<>();
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(),2);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        for (int i = 0; i < IMAGE_IDS.length; i++) {
            images.add(new ImageListHandler(IMAGE_IDS[i]));
        }
        GalleryAdapter adapter = new GalleryAdapter(getApplicationContext(), images);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.setOnItemClickListener(onItemClickListener);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("test", "hello");
        GameFragment9 fragobj = new GameFragment9();
        fragobj.setArguments(bundle);

    }
```

GameFragment9.java <- Fragment where I expect to receive the image's id (in this case obviously just a hello message)

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
    if (bundle != null){
        myValue = bundle.getString("test");
    }

    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), myValue, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

GameActivity9.java <- Hosts the Fragment that starts the Activity

public class GameActivity9 extends AppCompatActivity {

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_game9);
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        GameFragment9 fm1 = new GameFragment9();
        PictureHolder9Fragment fm2 = new PictureHolder9Fragment();
        if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment9One, fm1).commit();
        }
        else if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE){
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment9Oneh, fm1).commit();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment9Twoh, fm2).commit();
        }
    }
}
```

I added the if because otherwise I got a NullPointerException. The actual code is very large so I put here only the part involved in the communication.
PD: Actual GameFragment9 code: https://gist.github.com/Miguengineer/76df4ae7c17eb6bbf9c0328a5b5ca4b1
Actual ImageGallery: https://gist.github.com/Miguengineer/10e42985792b253fbf583559392cbc93

Comment: where is your fragment transaction?

Comment: Added the activity that hosts the fragment

Comment: ImageGallery.java has any transaction?

Comment: It hasn't. ImageGallery is just a simple Activity without fragments.

Comment: logically this code is ok. I think the problem is happening in others segment as this code is just demo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `GameFragment9` call [startActivityForResult()](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result) e.g:

```
val requestCode = 1001
val imageIntent = Intent(requireActivity(), ImageGallery::class.java)
startActivityForResult(imageIntent, requestCode)
```

also in `GameFragment9`, handle the result:

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent) {
    // Check which request we're responding to
    if (requestCode == 1001) {
        // Make sure the request was successful
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            // The user picked an image. Inspect data Intent.
            val selectedImageId = data.getIntExtra("image_id", -1)
        }
    }
}
```

In `ImageGallery`, once user has selected an image:

```
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, Intent().apply {
   putExtra("image_id", 1)
})
finish()
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a walkaround. This might not be an efficient solution (because it seems I'm starting an intent multiple times) nor an smart one but at least it works.

From ImageGallery (where the images are) I start the activity that holds the fragment sending data:

```
 @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(ImageGallery.this, GameActivity9.class);
        intent.putExtra("message", "This message is a test");
        startActivity(intent);
    }
};
```

Since it starts a new Activity, from there I'll send the data to the fragment:

```
// Get data back
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String message = intent.getStringExtra("message");
    Bundle data = new Bundle();
    data.putString("key", message);
```

Finally in the fragment I get my data:

```
  @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
        if (bundle != null){
            test = bundle.getString("key");
        }

        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), test, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

It works! However as I said, it seems just a walkaround, so I'll wait for a better answer or comments to improve mine.